# How to restrict tab key handler event in gwt

Tags: events, gwt, tabs, key

I am using GWT  components for web page. In my page I used ten text boxes. I want to block "tab" key event for navigate one text box to another text box.

Expected Approach: If I pressed tab key it wont go to another text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somthing like this.

```
window.onkeydown = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is GWT not javascript but one can use your idea

Answer (score 0):

Use [NativePreviewEventHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.NativePreviewEvent.html) and use the logic mentioned by Mayank Pandya, which is

```
if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Check for the `Tabkey` keycode. I am not sure about it.