# Blocking tab key in a web page

Tags: javascript, events, keydown, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have a web app in which the users rapidly respond to neuropsychological stimuli using the `Q` and `P` keys (this is not changeable). Problem is, sometimes users mistakenly move their finger and then press the `tab` key, in which case the focus is shifted from the page body (which I understand is the default, using `activeElement`) to somewhere else in the browser window (tabs, address bar, ...).

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063277/how-to-restrict-tab-key-handler-event-in-gwt) question and indeed have tried to use both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` upon catching the keydown event, but this doesn't help. If, for example, I add an alert - it alerts and then still goes on to change the focus.

Does anyone has an idea on how to prevent this, except customizing the browser to completely block thie `tab` key?

some code reference:

```
var ansFlag = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keydown);

function showTarget(){
    draw(stimInfo());
    run = setTimeout(advance,maxResponseTime);
    ansFlag = true;
    startTime = performance.now();  
}

function keydown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (ansFlag){
        endTime = performance.now();
        if ((keyCode == Q_KEY) || (keyCode == P_KEY)) {
            response_given = true;
            clearTimeout(run);
            advance();
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }       
    }
    else{
        if(e.key == "Tab"){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("tab!!!");
            if(e.defaultPrevented){
                console.log("saved the day!");
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a trick for this that might help.

When you press the tab key, the browser focuses only on your input.
You can hide this input

Of course I didn't see any code from you, but maybe this example will help you

```js
const playground = document.querySelector('.playground');
const focusInput1 = playground.querySelector('#focus1');

window.addEventListener('keydown' , function (e) {

    if(e.keyCode === 9){
        focusInput1.focus();
    }

});
```

```css
       .playground{
            background-color: blue;
            height: 500px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .other{
            background-color: red;
            height: 500px;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="playground">
        <input id="focus1">
        <input id="focus2">
    </div>

    <div class="other">

    </div>
```

Comment: Thankful. I tried your code and I didn't see any problem. It worked for me

Comment: Thanks, the solution was using `===` rather than `==` and adding `$("#body").focus()`